# Filling in a small ditch

Tags: irrigation

I have a small ditch that I dug to route some water. It turns out that it does not work, so I was wanting to fill it back in. The ditch is about a foot deep in some places. Can I compact new topsoil with a large block of wood and a sledge hammer?

Comment: How wide and long is this ditch?  The right tool is called a "tamper", but often getting the soil damp and walking on it can work if the ditch is small.

Comment: At the widest point, it is about 2 feet wide. It is about 15 to 20 feet long.

Comment: Based on that size, I agree with Ecnerwal.  That's really not even worth buying a tamper unless this is the sort of thing you will do often.

Answer (score 3):

If your available tools include a sledgehammer, just use that, held vertically, head down, pick it up and drop it, repeatedly, every 2 or 3 inches of soil fill (you cannot effectively tamp thicker layers of soil with hand tools.)

Forget the wood block.

Comment: Right. Gravity is your friend. Your own boots would work better than whacking a board.

Comment: Another question: Should the ground dirt and the topsoil be wet or neither or both? It seems like when I use the tamper I bought it just splashes mud when wet. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: damp, not wet ... just mist the dirt lightly